# reading and writing text file in c

Tags: c, file, loops, text, eof

a simple program to perform writing operation to a text file and then read and display the text from file.
 How do I rectify it and how to avoid using "#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
I am using visual studios 2018
I have tried multiple times but the output seems to go infinit[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Le5x.png)

```
   #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
    void main()
    {
        FILE *fp1, *fp2;
        fp1 = fopen("text.txt", "w");
        printf("enter no of lines");
        int line;
        scanf("%d", &line);

        char txt[1000];
        for (int i=0; i < line; i++)
        {
            gets( txt);
            fprintf(fp1, "s", txt);

        }
        fclose(fp1);
        char txt2[1000];
        fp2 = fopen("text.txt", "r");
        while (1)
        {
            fgets(txt2, 1000, fp2);

            if (txt2 == EOF)
                break;
            printf("%s", txt2);
        }
        fclose(fp2);
    }`
```

Comment: `if (txt2 == EOF)
                break;`?!?!  Turn on all compiler warnings.

Comment: txt2 being character buffer will not be EOF . you need to change the condition to fgets(txt2, 100,fp) != null to avoid infinite loop

Comment: does this method not work for strings like in the case for characters?https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-file-io/